# intValue() method for conversion of bigInteger to integer is giving wrong results

Tags: java, biginteger

```
static BigInteger []fact = new BigInteger[1000003];
```

this array contains the factorial of integers from 0 to 1000003

I have X as a BigInteger variable which is coming from a modulo operation

```
 while(m.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(0)) == 1 ||  n.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(0)) == 1){

        if(m.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(0)) == 1 || m.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(0)) == 0)
        {
            x = m.mod(mod);
            m = m.divide(mod);

        }
```

Now when I'm trying "fact[X]" it is giving this error at "fact[X]":

```
 BigInteger cannot be converted to int
        temp = (fact[x].multiply(fact[(x.subtract(y)).intValue()])).mod(mod);
```

after changing X to X.intValue() the value of X is getting Changed.

How can i access fact[X]?
help!!

Comment: read yor question 5 times but still didnt understand

Comment: So you want to say that your data member `temp` is of type `int` and you are trying to assign `BigInteger` value to it

Comment: Post a complete, reproducible test case. Tell us what its output should be according to you, and what it is in reality.

Comment: I downvoted, because the description don't illustrate clearly the statement that is expressed in the question (that is actually not a question). I agree with @JBNizet comment. IMHO question would require either a big edit or to be deleted

Comment: is it fine now. @superbob

Comment: What is `m`? What is `mod`? We need a runnable example so we can rebuild your problem on our machines. Btw instead of `BigInteger.valueOf(0)` use `BigInteger.ZERO`.

Comment: You should provide details on "_after changing X to X.intValue() the value of X is getting Changed._" espacially, an example of the value of `X` and the value of `X.intValue()`, for example an output of a `toString` for both of them. Then, as @JBNizet said, you should provide a reproducible test case, because if I would test it, I wouldn't know how

Comment: m and n are taken from user and are BigIntegers as well... value of mod is 1000003

Comment: if the value of X is 3 the the value of X.intValue() is coming 500002

Comment: I don't believe you. `BigInteger.valueOf(3).intValue()` yields `3`, not `500002`.

Comment: If these variables carry user input, then tell what you've entered to get that result (3 turns to 50002).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make the difference between `BigInteger` and `int` or `Integer`. There is no automatic conversion (autoboxing/unboxing) between `BigInteger` and `int`. Also, the dimension of an array of objects is always an `int`. Then each time you want to access an element in your `BigInteger` array, you have to explicitly convert the index value into an `int`, this is done by calling `BigInteger#intValue()`.
I tried to comment your code, assuming there is no problems in the `x` and `y` computing.
Note that an array of `BigInteger` contains only `null` *references* when you create it. Meaning you need to have create and set the array element before trying to do something on it.

```
final int max = 1000003;
BigInteger [] fact = new BigInteger[max];
BigInteger mod = BigInteger.valueOf(max);
BigInteger x = ...; // computed somewhere
BigInteger y = ...; // computed somewhere

BigInteger temp = 
   fact[x.intValue()]          // x is a BI, take intValue() to access array element
     .multiply(                // operands are BI
        fact[x.subtract(y)     // operands are BI
                 .intValue()]) // take intValue() to access array
                    .mod(mod); // operands are BI, result is BI
```

Comment: that's what I did. but X.intValue() is coming different than X.

Comment: without the code where you compute x and y, we can't say. But if you test `BigInteger.valueOf(12345).intValue() == 12345` it shall be true. Be aware that x and y should always be `< 1000003` in your program.

Answer (score 1):

array index should be integer. If you are using `fact[X]` then X must be **integer** not `BigInteger`

change your this logic if `x` and `y` is `BigInteger`

```
 temp = (fact[x].multiply(fact[(x.subtract(y)).intValue()])).mod(mod);
```

to

```
 temp = (fact[x.intValue()].multiply(fact[(x.subtract(y)).intValue()])).mod(mod);
```

Comment: but X.intValue() is giving different value

Comment: how you are assigning the value of x,y and mod ??

Comment: mod has the value 1000003

Comment: values of x and y are coming from another modulo operation